# Help with a recurring error message

Tags: package-management, dependencies

My minipc running Ubuntu 20.04 works fine but an error message notification comes up after using it for a while after booting it up, as follows:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: Opening the cache (E:can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_thierry-f_fork-michael-gruz__ubuntu__dists__focal__InRelease-fopen(13: Permission denied), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

I am not a PC expert and fairly new to Linux and would appreciate advice as to what to do.
I don't even know how to run package manger from a right-click. Where do I find the line I must delete please?

I ran apt-get in terminal and got the following: but I don't know what to do next?

```
paul@paul-histton:~$ apt-get
apt 2.0.9 (amd64)
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-get is a command line interface for retrieval of packages
and information about them from authenticated sources and
for installation, upgrade and removal of packages together
with their dependencies.

Most used commands:
  update - Retrieve new lists of packages
  upgrade - Perform an upgrade
  install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
  reinstall - Reinstall packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
  remove - Remove packages
  purge - Remove packages and config files
  autoremove - Remove all unused packages automatically
  dist-upgrade - Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)
  dselect-upgrade - Follow dselect selections
  build-dep - Configure build-dependencies for source packages
  satisfy - Satisfy dependency strings
  clean - Erase downloaded archive files
  autoclean - Erase old downloaded archive files
  check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies
  source - Download source archives
  download - Download the binary package into the current directory
  changelog - Download and display the changelog for the given package

See apt-get(8) for more information about the available commands.
Configuration options and syntax is detailed in apt.conf(5).
Information about how to configure sources can be found in sources.list(5).
Package and version choices can be expressed via apt_preferences(5).
Security details are available in apt-secure(8).
                                        This APT has Super Cow Powers.
```

Comment: Remove that line for checking the PPA .

Comment: What is the last thing you changed on your system before the error started happening?

Comment: I don't think I changed anything. Only have had the automatic updates from Software Updater running, and there was a message about snaps not updating and I followed the instructions about that which seemed to work OK but I think this message was coming up before that,

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I added a response by editing my original post.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question; it doesn't make sense for it to be one half of a dialogue where the other half is down here in the comments. Updating your question is a good idea, but try to keep it in a form which makes sense for new visitors.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show the contents of your package sources, i.e. the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any additional files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? Probably one of them is broken (and probably the one which is acting up is named something like "ppa.launchpad.net_thierry-f_fork-michael-gruz.list"; probably [this repo](https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz))

Comment: Something installed from here; https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f